# Rails some pages https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, https

I want to have 'user pages',`resources :users`, with `https` and rest of my app should be served over `http`

for example `https://myapp.com/user/1` and `http://myapp.com`

How can i do it? in rails

Is there any gem?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: If you use http for some page, an attacker can include a fake login page, or replace your secure https link by http link and do a Man in the Middle of your entire website, even page supposed to be secure. The only secure way to do it is to activate https everywhere, redirect http to https and use HSTS.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use constraints:

```
resources :users, constraints: {protocol: /https/}
```